# How to fix TypeError. Not sure what is wrong

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\file\path\to\json-parsing.py", line 33, in parse_output_file
    session['duration'] = session['end_time'] - session['start_time'] if session['end_time'] is not None else None
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Can someone explain?

My code is below:

```
import json     #import json and datetime libraries
from datetime import datetime

def parse_output_file(file_path):   #function to load json file
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    
    sessions = {}   #initialize empty dictionary
    
    for record in data:     #parse through array for each record
        session_id = record['id']
        session_type = record['type']
        timestamp = int(record['timestamp'])
        comments = record.get('comments', '')
        
        if session_id not in sessions: #creates new session_id if session_id is not found
            sessions[session_id] = {'id': session_id, 'start_time': None, 'end_time': None, 'duration': None, 'late_return': False, 'damaged': False, 'comments': ''}
        
        if session_type == 'START':     #checks session type and sets start time and end time
            sessions[session_id]['start_time'] = timestamp
        elif session_type == 'END':
            sessions[session_id]['end_time'] = timestamp
            if sessions[session_id]['end_time'] is not None:
                sessions[session_id]['damaged'] = bool(comments) #sets damaged and comments keys in the dictionary if present
                sessions[session_id]['comments'] = comments
    
    for session in sessions.values():
        start_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(session['start_time']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if session['start_time'] is not None else None
        if session['end_time'] is not None:
            end_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(session['end_time']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        else:
            end_time = None
        session['duration'] = session['end_time'] - session['start_time'] if session['end_time'] is not None else None
        late_return = session['duration'] > 24 * 3600 if session['duration'] is not None else False      #checks is the session is late by comparing to 24 hours
        
        
        session['late_return'] = late_return
        
        print(f"Session ID: {session['id']}")   #iterate through sessions dictionary and prints data
        print(f"Start Time: {start_time}")
        print(f"End Time: {end_time}")
        print(f"Duration: {session['duration']} seconds")
        print(f"Late Return: {late_return}")
        print(f"Damaged: {session['damaged']}")
        print(f"Comments: {session['comments']}")
        print()
    
    # Store summary records to a file
        
# Replace 'path/to/your/file.json' with the actual path to your JSON file
file_path = r'output.json'

# Usage
parse_output_file(file_path)`
```

I am trying to run this python script to parse a JSON file and have an output summary.

Comment: You only set `session['start_time']` when you see `session_type == START`. If there's no `START` type, it's left at `None`, and you can't subtract it. You need to figure out why you have some sessions that have been ended but were never started. If you rotate the log files, it was probably started in a previous log.

Comment: An expression like `a - b if a is not None else None` is treated as `a - (b if a is not None else None)`, which will end up as `None - None` if `a` is None, and you'll get another TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
start = session['start_time']
end = session['end_time']

if end is None or start is None:
    session['duration'] = None
else:
    session['duration'] = end - start
```